# How can we save custom field value to magento database via Event Observer Pattern

Tags: magento, events, design-patterns

I am working to add extra field in Magento `Newsletter Subscriber` Block via `Event Observer` Pattern.

Here is my code for the `Observer.php`:

```
<?php

class Scandi_Newsletter_Model_Observer
{
    public function newsletterSubscriberSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

     $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
     $name = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('subscriber_name');
     $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);
     $model = Mage::getModel('scandi/newsletter')->setSubscriberName($name)->save();
     //$subscriber->save();
     return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

I am not getting how to save the name value to database.

I have already executed the `installer` scripts & column has been added to database now i need to save the name value to database.

Here is my code for config.xml:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Scandi_Newsletter>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
  </Scandi_Newsletter>
</modules>
<global>
<resources>
        <scandi_newsletter_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Scandi_Newsletter</module>
            <class>Scandi_Newsletter_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
        </scandi_newsletter_setup>
        <newsletter_write>
    <connection>
    <use>core_write</use>
    </connection>
    </newsletter_write>
    <newsletter_read>
    <connection>
    <use>core_read</use>
    </connection>
    </newsletter_read>

    </resources>
     <events>
   <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
      <observers>
         <scandi_newsletter_model_observer>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Scandi_Newsletter_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>newsletterSubscriberSaveBefore</method>
        </scandi_newsletter_model_observer>
      </observers>
   </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
</events>
</global>   
</config>
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!!

How can I save the subscriber name in database.

Hello Everyone,

I am able to print the subscriber name,My mistake i was missing adding the subscriber name in subscriber.phtml file.For now I am using this code for Observer.php:-

```
<?php

class Scandi_Newsletter_Model_Observer
{
    public function newsletterSubscriberSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
    $name = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('subscriber_name');
 $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);
 $subscriber->save(); 
    print_r($subscriber->getData());

?>
```

Now Can Anybody assist me how can I save this value in database & also I need to display this vale in admin panel Newsletter Grid.

Comment: Try to print `$model->getData()` and see if you get `subscriber_name`

Comment: Hey Slimshaddyyy.Thanks for the response.  I have tried your suggestion but unfortunately it's displaying error on this:-Fatal error: Call to a member function setSubscriberName() on a non-object in /home/eatloca8/public_html/app/code/local/Scandi/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php on line 11

Comment: Could you pls post the error ?

Comment: shweta_kaushish,put your config.xml

Comment: @AmitBera :-Above Post is edited by adding config.xml code & other progress steps.Please have a look!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope, your installer  not working,It should be

```
<resources>
            <scandi_newsletter_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </scandi_newsletter_setup>
            <custommoule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </custommoule_read>
            <scandi_newsletter_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </scandi_newsletter_write>

    </resources>
```

Comment: Amit,Thanks for the response.Installer is working fine & i am able to save the values in database..Now the only part left with how can we display this value in backend Grid of Newsletter Subscriber...Any Idea about that??

Answer (score 0):

Yippee,I am able to save the values in database.Here is the updated code

**Package Name:-Scandi**

**Module Name:Newsletter**

1.)First update you subscriber.phtml by adding the extra field required

**2.)Crate Observer.php at 
magento\app\code\local\Scandi\Newsletter\Model\Observer.php:-**

```
 <?php

    class Scandi_Newsletter_Model_Observer
    {
        public function newsletterSubscriberSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
        $name = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('subscriber_name');
     $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);
    ?>
```

**3.)Create your Installer Script to add custom fields to database:-
:-app\code\local\Scandi\Newsletter\sql\scandi_newsletter_setup\install-0.1.0**

```
    $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->run("
     ALTER TABLE {$installer->getTable('newsletter_subscriber')}
     ADD (`name` TEXT NULL) ");
     $installer->endSetup();

?>
```

**4.) Config.xml as posted above**